# How to determine whether two "ref" variables refer to the same variable, even if null?

Tags: c#

How can I determine whether two `ref` variables refer to the same variable – even if both variables contain `null`?

Example:

```
public static void Main( string[] args )
{
    object a = null;
    object b = null;

    Console.WriteLine( AreSame( ref a, ref b ) ); // Should print False
    Console.WriteLine( AreSame( ref a, ref a ) ); // Should print True
}

static bool AreSame<T1, T2>( ref T1 a, ref T2 b )
{
    // ?????
}
```

Things I have tried that don't work:

- `return object.ReferenceEquals( a, b );` (Returns true in both test cases)
- `unsafe { return &a == &b; }` (Cannot take the address of a managed object)

Comment: Isn´t the first example what you ment be "even if both are null"? A reference can´t be null btw, it can only point to nothing, which is your first example. Apart from this I suppose you won´t need `ref`-keyword for this unless you want to change the reference (not the referenced object).

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is supported, you're not supposed to manipulate the `ref` variable *references* directly, at all.

Comment: May I ask why you need to do this at all? This sounds like an X/Y problem.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Maybe the title doesn't precisely reflect what I'm after. In my `AreSame` method, I want to tell whether or not the two passed references point to the same variable, regardless of what those variables contain (or don't). This would be equivalent to comparing the addresses of the variables in C/C++.

Comment: But *why* do you need that information? The caller should *know* if it passes the same variable, so you could expand your functions parameters with a flag  that tells it if the two variables are the same

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why do you want to know this?

Comment: I don't think it really matters. Even if there's better way to do whatever he's doing, I'm at least interested if there's a more elegant way to solve this than trying to assign temp values.

Comment: I was trying to keep the question concise, but since several people have asked why, I shall attempt to elaborate: I have several class-level variables of the same type that need to be processed very similarly. It's cleaner in this instance to consolidate the processing into a common method that handles the minor differences based on the variable that is passed in. I _could_ pass in an additional parameter to identify the variable, but it seems like I should be able to tell from the variable itself which one I'm operating on.

Comment: You really shouldn't design your method like this but that's your choice.

Comment: You can probably do it in managed C++. I found this - http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/07/4395.aspx.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Ordinarily I'd agree with you … and I may yet agree with you again. This is the first time I've run into a situation where this approach seemed like a good solution. It may prove not to be, though.

Comment: It seems like it could be neatly solved using an interface on the object that contains the field.  Then you can pass only interface handles instead of byref variables, compare the objects (using `ReferenceEquals` on the interface handle) as well as read and write the member.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can actually just use the [`Unsafe.AreSame` method](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/0f6f5ea8f08dc7e033b4bf998f54e6e731f3bfa1/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.il#L412-L420) from the [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/) package.

This will compare references directly and is the *cleanest* solution. The method is written in IL and simply compares the references, because, well... you *can* do that in IL :)

If you want to compare two references of different types, you can cast one of them using [this overload of `Unsafe.As`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/0f6f5ea8f08dc7e033b4bf998f54e6e731f3bfa1/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.il#L298-L304):

```
static bool AreSame<T1, T2>(ref T1 a, ref T2 b) 
    => Unsafe.AreSame(ref Unsafe.As<T1, T2>(ref a), ref b);
```

---

Here's another suggestion if casting a reference feels clunky: use [my InlineIL.Fody library](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/InlineIL.Fody) which lets you inject arbitrary IL code directly into your C# code:

```
static bool AreSame<T1, T2>(ref T1 a, ref T2 b)
{
    IL.Emit.Ldarg(nameof(a));
    IL.Emit.Ldarg(nameof(b));
    IL.Emit.Ceq();
    return IL.Return<bool>();
}
```

I'm suggesting this since it's easier than emitting code at runtime with Reflection.Emit, because you can't create a generic `DynamicMethod` and you would need to generate a dynamic type. You could also write an IL project but it also feels overkill just for one method.

Also, you avoid taking a dependency on an external library, if that is important to you.

---

Note that I wouldn't *completely* trust the `__makeref` and `Unsafe.AsPointer` solutions because of the possibility of a race condition: if you're unfortunate enough to get these conditions together:

- the two references are equal
- the GC is triggered by another thread *after* the first side of the comparison is evaluated but *before* the other one is
- your reference points somewhere to the managed heap
- the referenced object is moved by the GC for heap compaction purposes

Well, then the pointer that has already been evaluated won't be updated by the GC prior to the comparison, so you'll get an incorrect result.

Is it likely to happen? Not really. But it *could*.

The `Unsafe.AreSame` method always operates in byref space, so the GC can track and update the references at any time.

Comment: The signature of this looks like `bool Unsafe.AreSame<T>( ref T left, ref T right )`. At first, it's not clear this can be used if the two arguments are not known to be the same type at compile time. But `Unsafe` offers a solution with `ref T2 Unsafe.As<T1, T2>( ref T1 source )`: `Unsafe.AreSame( ref Unsafe.As<T1, T2>( ref left ), ref right )`.

Comment: @SWB Oh, I haven't noticed the two ref types weren't the same in your question, sorry. And sure enough, using `Unsafe.As` solves the problem. I've updated my answer, and added a second solution.

Answer (score 44):

There is a way without modifying the values, using unsafe code and the undocumented `__makeref` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object a = null;
    object b = null;

    Console.WriteLine(AreSame(ref a, ref b));  // prints False
    Console.WriteLine(AreSame(ref a, ref a));  // prints True
}

static bool AreSame<T1, T2>(ref T1 a, ref T2 b)
{
    TypedReference trA = __makeref(a);
    TypedReference trB = __makeref(b);

    unsafe
    {
        return *(IntPtr*)(&trA) == *(IntPtr*)(&trB);
    }
}
```

Note: The expression `*(IntPtr*)(&trA)` relies on the fact that [the first field of TypedReference](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/typedreference.cs,849048081561bd0c) is an `IntPtr` pointing to the variable we want to compare. Unfortunately (or fortunately?), there is no managed way to access that field -- not even with reflection, since `TypedReference` can't be boxed and, thus, can't be used with `FieldInfo.GetValue`.

Comment: *Sigh*, no bananas in sight. Good solution though!

Comment: _That's_ something I didn't know about before. Thanks!

Comment: ***undocumented** method* sounds fun

Answer (score 29):

Maybe this could be done by changing the reference to a temporary variable and checking if the other one changes as well.
I made a quick test, and this seems to work:

```
static bool AreSame(ref object a, ref object b) {
    var old_a = a;
    a = new object();
    bool result = object.ReferenceEquals(a, b);
    a = old_a;
    return result;
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    object a = null;
    object b = null;

    var areSame1 = AreSame(ref a, ref b); // returns false
    var areSame2 = AreSame(ref a, ref a); // returns true
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use `a = new object()` as this removes any chance that `b` can already have been set to `banana`.

Comment: That's actually a clever idea. It might just work for my current problem.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: you are absolutely right. I updated my answer, even if I'm sorry for not having a variable called `banana` anymore.

Comment: "Can you hold the banana for a moment?", "Yeah, sure, but why?", "Well, are you holding a banana now?", "Yes, uhm, you just told me to hold a banana; again, why?", "Ok good, thank you, now give me my banana back!", "BUT WHY, WHAT'S WITH THE BANANA???"

Comment: You can also remove the caching of the old value in `b`, as you're not (directly) modifying `b`.

Comment: True again, thanks. I would also like to mention that I'm in a meeting and trying really hard not to laugh out loud because of bananas.

Comment: You could reintroduce the banana by making it a local variable that you initialize to begin with, and compare b against this banana instead, this would also remove the chance that any other code actually gives b a banana.

Comment: I had thought about local bananas, but that looked a bit preposterous. Also, minions are definitely not helping.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that does not use the undocumented `__makeref` keyword. This makes use of the [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/) NuGet package:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public static void Main( string[] args )
{
    object a = null;
    object b = null;

    Console.WriteLine( AreSame( ref a, ref b ) ); // Prints False
    Console.WriteLine( AreSame( ref a, ref a ) ); // Prints True
}

unsafe static bool AreSame<T1, T2>( ref T1 a, ref T2 b )
{
    var pA = Unsafe.AsPointer( ref a );
    var pB = Unsafe.AsPointer( ref b );

    return pA == pB;
}
```